# im trying to re make the golden dragon from skyblock with commands and theres an error getting rid of what i wrote in the item description

Tags: minecraft-commands

when i added the abilities the first 3 it went fine but after i added a fourth it started to remove the description and the effects and when i tried to remove it the same problem kept happening (i bolded the issue)

/give @p minecraft:player_head{HideFlags:127,display:{Name:'[{"italic":false,"text":"(lvl 200) ","color":"gray"},{"text":"Shiny Anubis Golden Dragon","color":"gold"}]',Lore:['[{"italic":false,"text":"Combat Pet","color":"dark_gray"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"dark_gray"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Crit Chance: ","color":"gray"},{"text":"+10%","color":"green"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Crit Damage: ","color":"gray"},{"text":"+50%","color":"green"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Strength: ","color":"gray"},{"text":"+50%","color":"green"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"green"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Gold’s Power","color":"gold"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Adds + ","color":"gray"},{"text":"100","color":"green"},{"text":" more damage to ","color":"gray"},{"text":"❁ Strength","color":"red"},{"italic":false,"text":" to all netherite weapons.","color":"gray"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"gray"}]','**[{"italic":false,"text":"Shining Scales","color":"gold"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Grants +","color":"gray"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"10 ❁ Strength ","color":"red"},{"text":"and +2","color":"gray"},{"text":" ✯ Magic find","color":"cyan"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"to your pet for each digit in your ","color":"gray"},{"text":"gold collection","color":"gold"},{"text":" ❁ Strength.","color":"red"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"red"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Dragon’s Greed","color":"gold"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Increases most stats by ","color":"gray"},{"text":"10%","color":"green"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"green"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Legendary Treasure","color":"gold"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Gain ","color":"gray"},{"text":"0.25%","color":"green"},{"italic":false,"text":" ❁ Strength.","color":"red"}]’,’[{"italic":false,"text":"for every million coins in your bank","color":"green"}]**','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"gray"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"Hold this pet in your offhand to","color":"yellow"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"use your pet!","color":"yellow"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"yellow"}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"LEGENDARY PET","color":"gold","bold":true},{"text":"","color":"gold","bold":false}]','[{"italic":false,"text":"","color":"gold"}]']},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.knockback_resistance",Name:"generic.knockback_resistance",Slot:"offhand",Amount:999999,Operation:0,UUID:[I;1011937184,1059377347,1007249921,1641519061]},{AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage",Name:"generic.attack_damage",Slot:"offhand",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUID:[I;1088496782,1012008583,1003890789,1243522093]}],SkullOwner:minceraft1} 1